# jQuery hide / unhide toggle image

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have divs that show and hide by clicking on a little arrow.
Calendar entries that can unfold more info when clicked. So far so good.

I would like the little arrow that i use to be able to unhide the content to change from an "up" to a "down" state or even better rotate 180 degrees when the content is visible.

```
    jQuery('.openheader').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
}).parent().next().hide();
```

the .openheader class is applied to the link around the image of the arrow.

while i'm at it - a nice feature would also be if there is no content in the .calendarhidden DIV (the div containing the extra infos), be able to hide the corresponding link or image.

any ideas? can't get my head around how to incorporate it into the toggle action.
thanks 
*edit: here is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marknolan/gtEdy/

Comment: Posting your HTML or a jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Agree with j08691. A Fiddle could tell us what exactly we're working with. From what you've said, you could look at changing the CSS (background-image) from an up-arrow and a down-arrow on the divisions. Achieve this with: $(this).css("background-image", ""); Just an idea.

Comment: good idea... i'll set it up on jsfiddle thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/marknolan/gtEdy/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this like so `if (document.getElementById(event.target.id).src.indexOf('right.png') > 0) {
        document.getElementById(event.target.id).src = 'path/arrow_left.png';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(event.target.id).src = 'path/arrow_right.png';
    }`

**edit** should say this requires function(event)